# NUnit .NET Core running through ReSharper

Tags: .net-core, nunit, resharper, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to run NUnit tests for a .NET Core 2.0 project in Visual Studio 2017 through ReSharper. I've had the test .proj assembly set both as console application and class library. So it doesn't seem to be the output type. The solution does not discover any unit test and just displays no results with 0 tests run.

Here is my .csproj file for the tests project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>eCorp.WebStore.OrderService.Tests</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>eCorp.WebStore.OrderService.Tests</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.9.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\OrderService.Domain\OrderService.Domain.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Core\OrderService.Infrastructure\OrderService.Infrastructure.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I found this already:
*[Run NUnit tests in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36578232/run-nunit-tests-in-net-core)*

None of the provided solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: I'd consider changing your accepted answer to D.G.'s. The current accepted answer (not possible) perhaps _was_ correct, but now it all works like a charm with the correct packages installed.

Comment: @ToddMenier also need ReSharper running >2018.X (Updating mine to 2018.2.3 fixed the issue)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I solved by installing the following NuGet packages

- NUnit
- NUnit3TestAdapter
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk

Comment: Wow, adding Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: And restarting VS, and updating resharper

Comment: See @mdickin answer below if this doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/a/49516284/1811110

Comment: Resharper hinted to me I needed to install `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, but after installing it, Resharper still didn't recognize the tests. So I tried restarting VS, and then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper is known to have problems running .NET Core 2.0 tests in Visual Studio 2017. Try to run them without ReSharper.

For more information see this Stack Overflow question and answers: *[.NET Core 2.0 and xUnit doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163611/net-core-2-0-and-xunit-doesnt-run)*.

Answer (score 3):

If you've installed the packages in [D.G's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445769/nunit-net-core-running-through-resharper/48949918#48949918) and it still doesn't work, check if you need to update ReSharper. That worked for me.